# Host Header Site Collections /w multi tenancy

Tags: 404, multi-tenancy, host-header

I basically followed the steps in Spence Harbars Guide http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010mt1.aspx do create a multi-tenancy farm with host-header site-collections.

For some reason I cannot supply a template when creating the tenant-sites, I always get "There are no addresses available for this application." So I create the new site without a template and then call `set-spsite -template sts#0`. This gives me the same message, but looking with SharePoint Manager in the site, I have STS as the associated web-template.

However ... when I open up IE and want to browse to the site (http:/portal.corp-a.local) I get a 404 ...

OK, now I'm lost/stuck. What went wrong? ULS doesn't include any error. Any hints?

Comment: Could you give more details about your web application, Host header of web application etc? How did you test the application? with DNS or Host file entry? Rajesh

Comment: I have added A records to the DNS of the tenant pointing to my shared sharepoint-server.

Comment: What is the web application port ? Is it a host header web application? is your host header site collection matched the subdomain of the web application host header? I can help you if you can give the web application and site collection URL name as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no addresses available" is because you have a service that is not started, most likely the subscription service, which is require for multi-tenancy.

Comment: Dooh! What a bummer. How did that slip? I have no clue!